Is there a function that could tell me if both of two strings fall in one of the cells in a column/row?

General question: is there a function which can tell me if any one of the cells in a column contains both of two different strings.

A Catalogue and a Bibliography
I have a very large catalogue of books in the library where I work. The catalogue has the names, publication dates, titles, publishers in a specific format. One instance: Celan, Paul (1959): Sprachgitter. Frankfurt/M.: S. Fischer Verlag, 66 (1) S.). I have each in a single cell, in a column (80,000 cells...).
Then I have a list of names (in the format "second name, first name" as in the catalogue) and titles. They're from a large bibliography of German poetry. These are are in two separate columns.
Task
I want a function that I can put next to my bibliography columns (the name and title columns) which says if that name and that title fall in any of the catalogue cells.
Suggested Solution
A function that tells me if (and if so, where) the cell is in the Catalogue column that contains both of the two different strings from the two bibliography columns
Nota Bene
I'm sure there are no repetitions of titles, names, or bibliographical entries.
It has to be about containing both of two separate strings because of the date standing in the middle of the name and the title in the bibliographical entries. It would take really long to get the dates...
I just can't figure out how to do it... I have looked about Excel... my naive excel thinking just made me think that I could put "AND" in there somewhere... This was something I attempted :((( =ISNUMBER(SEARCH((Bibliography cell with name AND Bibliography cell with title), Catalogue column)
Thank you.

Magic disappearing comments or delete and re-post question?

=CELL("address",INDEX(searchRange,MATCH(valToMatch,searchRange,matchType)  -- the Match Function determines if your search value is found.  INDEX gets the index from that result, CELL gets the cell value from the INDEX.  You will need to make a regex to isolate your name and title, and use the regex in the valToMatch parameter.  You'll need to lookup matchValue and how to do your regex, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

You can use formula
=XLOOKUP(TRUE;ISNUMBER(FIND(B2;Table1[Book])*FIND(C2;Table1[Book]));Table1[Book])


The formula returns the first cell where both B2 and C2 texts are found. It's not related neither Name nor Title.
Any of B2 or C2 cells can be empty to find the single text only.

If you need the list of matching entries:
=FILTER(Table1[Book];ISNUMBER(FIND(B2;Table1[Book])*FIND(C2;Table1[Book])))



If you need the list of matching entries where any of texts is found:
[D8] =FILTER(
  Table1[Book];
  ISNUMBER(FIND(B8;Table1[Book]))+ISNUMBER(FIND(C8;Table1[Book]))>0
)



Using XMATCH with wildcard to match "name (year): title" (Excel 2021 and later):
=LET(
catalogue, $A$2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, $A:$A <> "", $A:$A, , , -1),
name, $E2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, $E:$E <> "", $E:$E, , , -1),
title, $F2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, $F:$F <> "", $F:$F, , , -1),
IFERROR(XMATCH(TRIM(name) & " (????): " & TRIM(title) & "*", catalogue, 2), ""))


$A$2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, $A:$A <> "", $A:$A, , , -1)
is used to automatically in rows from the first cell to the last non-blank row
This is an array formula, so enter it only the first cell (G2 in the example)


To get the detail, enter the following formula (entered in H4 in the example):
=LET(
catalogue, $A$2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, $A:$A <> "", $A:$A, , , -1),
name, $E2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, $E:$E <> "", $E:$E, , , -1),
title, $F2:XLOOKUP(TRUE, $F:$F <> "", $F:$F, , , -1),
IFERROR(INDEX(catalogue, XMATCH(TRIM(name) & " (????): " & TRIM(title) & "*", catalogue, 2), 1), ""))

